# Play store is downloading tablet versions instead of phone's ones

Tags: google-play-store, custom-roms

I recently flashed Resurrection Remix Custom ROM on my LG G3. Once finished, I flashed Gapps and everything worked just fine.

However, I noticed a strange behavior while searching and downloading apps with play store. Play Store is downloading tablet version instead of phone's one. I noticed that after installing my bank's app, since the phone's version has a new GUI design, and the one I installed has an out-dated one.

In addition, I'm not able to find some applications, like Amazon.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: I forget the name of the config file that the Play Store uses to determine this sort of thing, but it's a core part of the ROM.  Editing it can be pretty dangerous ... I would suggest using a different and properly configured ROM.

Comment: I'm guessing that your `/system/build.prop` values aren't correct. Check with other G3 owners and compare your `ro.product.device`, `ro.product.board`, and `ro.product.model` values.